# App Registration in azure giving error - Failed to create aptabi application. Error detail: Insufficient privileges to complete the operation

Tags: azure, powerbi, powerbi-embedded

Actually I want to use PowerBI embedded service in my web application. 
I have checked Azure made some changes to create PowerBI workspace Collection, to use Non-PowerBI users and PowerBi users. 
To use PowerBI Workspace Collection service, I need to register an app in portal.
but while registering app I am getting error - "Failed to create aptabi application. Error detail: Insufficient privileges to complete the operation."
I have already in Azure Active Directory.

Please help to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Power BI embedding has been recently updated. So I suggest revisiting this again, if it is still an issue. There is some up-to-date documentation here: [Embedding with Power BI](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/powerbi-developer-embedding/)